# get data from post function in parent().parent() location

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

how to get jquery value using '

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ef_StdInfo_todb.php",
    data: formVals(),
    success: function(data, msg){
    $(this).parent().parent().html(data);
    $(this).parent().parent().('#status_Div").text(msg);
   }
```

'
 nothing happens. but if i put direct div name $("anydiv") instead of parent, parent lines. then values appears.
what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector that Alex points out is correct however, not knowing how you are calling `$.ajax()` I will make some assumptions.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ef_StdInfo_todb.php",
    data: formVals(),
    success: function(data, msg) {
      $(this).parent().parent().find('#status_Div').text(msg);
   }
});
```

`this` is going to be a reference to your `xhr` object and not the element that you clicked on or triggered the `$.ajax` which would explain why your success call fails.

If called via a `.click()` simply create a variable to store the element clicked on.

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    var $that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ef_StdInfo_todb.php",
        data: formVals(),
        success: function(data, msg) {
          $that.parent().parent().html(data);
          $('#status_Div').text(msg);
       }
    });
});
```

*Side note*, since you are querying via `id` you could simply call `$('#status_Div').text(msg)` without worrying about `.parent()`

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/bqMXb/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent().parent().('#status_Div").text(msg);
```

This line is incorrect. You probably want `find()` there after the second call to `parent()`. You are also using `'` and `"` as delimiters in the same string. That won't work. Pick one or the other and be consistent.

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('#status_Div').text(msg);
```

Also, you can use `closest()` with a selector string to access parent nodes until one matches the selector. It can be useful to avoid multiple calls to `parent()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this help... this "find" helped me in some other stuff too..

Answer (score 1):

alex is right. Anyway, `$(this).parent().parent().html(data);` will replace anything existing inside parent().parent(), so `#status_Div` could only be found if it was included in `data`. Am I right?